# Incorrect SQL syntax, no obvious mistakes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, mysqli

The following MySQL statement reports incorrect SQL syntax when run by PHP but I can't find any obvious mistakes in it.

```
"INSERT INTO {$UserTable} (username, password, email, salt) VALUES ({$Username}, {$Password}, {$Email}, {$Salt});"
```

I added a few debug functions to my script in order to see what the issue is, but yet to notice the issue.

**Final Query**

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, salt) VALUES (TestUser, ea55336ae722b176a64eff46bbf7eeb0f5053a04f5e94670d719656dc496a8a754dd3e36ead83459020021526747b0a9fc82c397a40699e64f37ad2460a61067, TestEmail, EWEQPVVWIGX);
```

**Error message**

```
Unknown column 'TestUser' in 'field list'
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Almost, but the description of using PDO is woefully inadequate, as well as being almost a footnote. Plus pretending that the answers are "wrong" is childish at best, lying at worst. At 61k you should know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the individual values with single quotes.

```
 "INSERT INTO {$UserTable} (username, password, email, salt) VALUES ('{$Username}', '{$Password}', '{$Email}', '{$Salt}');"
```

Comment: Any reason for downvoting other answer??

Comment: Someone has downvoted mine too. :\

Comment: Probably @TheCommonSense, trying to draw more attention to his mediocre answer!

Answer (score 1):

Final Query should be

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, salt) 
VALUES ('TestUser', 'ea55336ae722b176a64eff46bbf7eeb0f5053a04f5e94670d719656dc496a8a754dd3e36ead83459020021526747b0a9fc82c397a40699e64f37ad2460a61067','TestEmail', 'EWEQPVVWIGX');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add single quotes around all strings of characters